Is this ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1 the same as a Delete and Rebuild Index in Indexing Options?
We have some windows.db files on a few machines that have grown to massive sizes in Windows 11; and I was wondering how to use Powershell 5 to clean these up.
I am aware of the Control Panel’s Indexing Options -> Advanced -> Rebuild Index, but I am uncertain if in Windows 11 the ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1 is the same thing.

What is the source of this ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1?

@Ramhound Download Reset Windows Search PowerShell script from Official Microsoft Download Center

Is ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1 the same as a Delete and Rebuild Index?
No. ResetWindowsSearchBox.ps1 fixes problems with Windows Search.

Repairing the search on Windows 10 has numerous possible fixes, but using the Reset Windows Search PowerShell Script is a simple, easy solution to try first.

Source: How to Reset Windows Search in Windows 10 & 11 - MajorGeeks
So what can I do?
You can defrag the index files:
sc config wsearch start=disabled
sc stop wsearch
esentutl.exe /d %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb
sc config wsearch start=delayed-auto
sc start wsearch

the standard tool for maintaining such databases, esentutl.exe (Extensible Storage Engine Utility – should be familiar to Exchange admins). The database is defragmented offline (it must not be used), so you will have to stop Widows Search service first.

You can remove and recreate the index files:
net stop "Windows Search"
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search" /v SetupCompletedSuccessfully /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
del %PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb
net start "Windows Search"

Source: How to Reduce Windows.edb Huge File Size
